# Task Scheduler doesn't like Floating License

Tags: fme-form

While trying to run an FME workspace weekly it has become clear that Task Scheduler won't open FME. I think this is due to missing the floating license credentials. Has anyone else run into this? If so, have you found a workaround?

Answer (score 2):

If it's running FME from the command line, using the same FME installation that is used to run the workspace within FME Desktop, then it should be fine. That installation is licensed and good to go.

What I suspect is more likely is a permissions problem. Check the Task Scheduler and see which user is the running the process:

[image]

Here I am running this as myself, so I know that if I can run it manually it will run automatically too. If it's a different user (particularly if it's accessing data on a shared drive or is not administrator) then that could be the cause.

Also, of course, check the button to allow it to run whether or not the user is logged on.

Here's the command I use for my example:

[image]

I use the full path because I have multiple FME instances installed, and that might be an issue for you if you are just using "fme" because it might not be running the executable you think.

In short, I doubt it's a license issue. If necessary turn on task history and check your logs to see what sort of error (if any) it is returning when it fails to run.

Comment: Also check the 'Run with highest privileges' (if have admin) this will prevent files or log files not getting written. (from past experience)

Comment: It's good practice to run these sorts of things from a service account with administrative privileges.